# CakePHP and Simpletest: Reset database data after each test is run?

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp, reset, simpletest

Is there a way to reset my database in between when tests run? Maybe something with test grouping? I need to load the same data for each test. Is there someway to automatically do this between each test? Thanks

Comment: Try drop-create your database over and over again. You can code a simple script to help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [fixtures](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1201/Preparing-test-data)

Comment: is there a way to auto generate a text file? my SQLdump is 20mb of text, and it will take a long time to put that into a fixture...

Comment: During development, you should use only small sets of data to test each specific part of your app. I don't think you need all 20MB of them in each test.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.